# Google Cloud Messaging - Same Device Multiple Applications

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I Run the sample demo application of Google Cloud messaging and i have received the pushed message. My question is if i have 2 two program on my device and i want to push messages to these two program according to my choice. for example i want to push message to the Program1 and then i want to push another message to only Program2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this post help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555180/android-gcm-same-sender-id-for-more-application/11555590#11555590

Comment: When obtaining the registration id i send (this,sender_id).  the sender id is same but the this value is different for the two program so may be it is possible to obtain different reg id, i thougt  :)

Comment: Even if you have the same ProjectID, each application should have its own push token so they would not be mixed.