# In GCM: Does API Project account have to be the same as Google Play Store account?

Tags: android, google-play, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have a backend for sending GCM push notifications that uses an API-project (sender_id) created under my google-account. It works great with an app published under my Google Play Store account (same google-account as API-project).

Now I have to publish an app for a friend under his Google Play Store account, and I would like to use the same sender_id I use in my own app (that way I do not need changes on my backend).

- Is this possible? Can his app under his Google Play Store account use a sender_id (API-project) created with a different google-account than Google Play Store google-account?
- If the answer is positive: is there any possibility that Google requires in the future that API-project and Google Play Store have to be in the same google-account? (for security reasons, for example)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only thing that requires the same API Project account and Play Store account is if you have to [link your application](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling) for Google Play Services.

Using the same senderID is actually welcomed (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555180/android-gcm-same-sender-id-for-more-application)). If that application is not yours, there are the obvious downsides of it being harder to maintain and debug, but if you're fine with that, having different accounts should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Andy. I had seen the linked question, but it is mentioned to use same senderID for all apps of the same developer, and this could also be understood as "all the apps under the same Google Play developer account". It is not clear if apps under other developer accounts (Google Play) are still welcome (or encouraged) to use same senderID.