# Firebase FCM practices (1 project vs multiple apps)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just updated my GCM implementation to Firebase.

I started with creating a FCM project and added one of my apps to it.
When I got to my second app, I created a new FCM project, but then found out I could link multiple apps to one project, so I linked the second app to my first project as well.

Now I have all my apps linked to one project and it works well, still I wonder if this is the best (most sensible!?) way to do it.
Because now everytime I download the "google-services.json" there is config stuff in it for ALL my linked apps, even though I don't need it in my current app (and I am not sure if I can delete the superfluous stuff (can I?)).

Are there any other ramifications for having one project only or is it even a good thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Are there any other ramifications for having one project only or is it even a good thing?*

Using a single project means a single Sender ID is also used. I think that you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587181/4625829) by @TrevorJohns (quoting the only necessary paragraph, for your concern.. I think):

> Developers are perfectly welcome (and encouraged) to use the same sender ID / API key for all of their apps.

---

*everytime I download the "google-services.json" there is config stuff in it for ALL my linked apps, even though I don't need it in my current app (and I am not sure if I can delete the superfluous stuff (can I?)).*

I tried it out (added an app, downloaded the google-services.json, deleted the details of the other app (make sure you don't delete the details of the app you want), copied it to the Application folder) and everything worked fine.

Cheers!