# Android GCM: same sender id for sdk in multiple apps in one phone

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a sdk that can be integrated in an application. Server for our sdk wants to use single GCM Id to send push notification. How to tackle the scenario where my sdk is integrated in two applications in same phone and as sdk in one application registers GCM, the GCM registered from sdk in other application expires ?

**FYI** I have reviewed this answer [Android GCM: same sender id for more application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555180/android-gcm-same-sender-id-for-more-application) but they are considering the app is installed in different device.

Answer (score 0):

> FYI I have reviewed this answer Android GCM: same sender id for more application but they are considering the app is installed in different device.

You did not get the answer. What matters is `registration Id` of the client (app). As long as you got it different per app, then it does not matter where it is installed and using (or not) same sender id is also irrelevant.

Comment: As I can understand from that answer, GCM id is the combination of device + package name of app, so the only option here to achieve what I have asked is to give different package name of my sdk for each app, right ?

Comment: No. It's linked to package id, but it does not contain it. None the less registration Id is being given to you by GCM/FCM so it's quite irrelevant how it is internally constructed. The main point is that each of your apps on the same device will get different id, so there's no conflict.