# Why does FCM changes token some times

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

What I learned about FCM is that its token never gets expired unless;

- The app deletes Instance ID
- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

I have provided a option to user to enable/disable notification, user clicks on disable and i send `null` to server, and `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` when user enable `push notifications`

Now some times it sends the same token when user re-enable the notifications, and few times it changes the `FCM Token`.

My Questions are:

1. Why does it change the `Token`, when nothing of the 4 conditions
   mentioned above are `true`, and if it's changing it randomly, then there is a chance that it changed the token at any point of time,
   and the server is sending the notification to the wrong Token.
2. I noticed that, if I clear data, and open the app, it hits for Token
   registration and gets the same token sometimes does it store `udid`
   of devices, or what mechanism, by which it knows that it's the same
   device.

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093189/firebase-fcm-registration-token). It is saying same as you are. Hope it clears your doubts

Answer (score 1):

For your Questions.

1) Security reason is behind changing of the `token`. If your app has a static token and if someone got that, they can have a control. Once the new Token generated you have to update it with your user data in the server. So you won't send it to the wrong token. this will happen only when your user went offline for a while.

2) Token generated by FCM is unique. The **FCM** token generated using your **Device id** and **App id**. So no other device will get the same token if your's changed. Complete mechanism of generating token can't be exposed for the same security purpose.

Comment: "*The FCM token generated using your Device id and App id"* - I think I remember this as well. Hi Bhuvanesh, could you also include your reference, I think it would be great to add it in.